# Can't get hook_uninstall to trigger

Tags: hooks, installation

In mymodule.install i try to implement a hook_uninstall call, but it never triggers. What am I doing wrong?

```
function hook_uninstall() {
echo "uninstalling";
...more stuff...
}
```

Comment: You'll need to supply more information for someone to know what's going on.  Are you literally naming the function `hook_uninstall` and not `mymodule_uninstall`? How are triggering the hook? Via Drush, via the module administration form?

Comment: Echoing content rarely works in Drupal as well. Is that how you are trying to determine the hook has been hit? Try `drupal_set_message('some message')` instead.

Comment: Replace hook_uninstall with mymodule_uninstall() and give it a go. Your uninstall hook should have same name as your module name to work.

Comment: My mistake as a newbie, thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the implementation of a hook never has a name starting with *hook_*; you always replace *hook_* with the machine name of the module, followed from an underscore. Similarly, the name of the file containing an implementation of `hook_uninstall()` must be the machine name of the module followed by .install.
So, if you are literally calling the function `hook_uninstall()`, and *mymodule* is not the machine name of your module, Drupal will never consider that function a hook implementation.

Second, if you are using `echo` to check if the hook is being invoked, you will not get any output. Use [`watchdog()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7.x) (Drupal 7) or `\Drupal::logger($module)->error($message)` (Drupal 8) inside a hook, if you want to verify a hook is invoked.

Third, `hook_uninstall()` is invoked from Drupal only when a module is uninstalled. There is no other way to be sure Drupal is invoking that hook, if not installing and uninstalling the module implementing it. In Drupal 7, don't get confused from disabling a module, and uninstalling it: Disabling a module doesn't cause Drupal to invoke `hook_uninstall()`.